# Get image type, PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to set an image type as a variable in PHP. I need to pull an image from the database, find it's image type and display it. At the moment it's only displaying jpg's.

The code for uploading is:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] != '') {
    $tempext = explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']);
    $tempext = strtolower($tempext[count($tempext) - 1]);
    switch($tempext) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $ext = '.jpg';
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $ext = '.gif';
            break;
        case 'png':
            $ext = '.png';
            break;
        default:
            $ext = false;
    }
    if($ext != false && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/profiles/' . $id . $ext)) {
        $imagesuccess = chmod($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/profiles/' . $id . $ext, 0644) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    } else {
        $imagesuccess = 'no';
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I've made a bit of progress, mostly cleaning up some foolish mistakes, but I still haven't gotten any images to appear.

Here's the updated switch case:

```
switch ($ext) { 
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                $ext = '.jpg';
                break;
            case 'gif':
                $ext = '.gif';
                break;
            case 'png':
                $ext = '.png';
        }
```

and image placement:

```
if(!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $imgurl . 'profiles/' . $r['id'] . $ext)) {
                    echo '<img src="' . $imgurl . 'profiles/unavailable.gif" id="profile-big-img" />' . PHP_EOL;
                } else {
                    echo '<p><img class="profileimg" src="' . $imgurl . 'profiles/' . $r['id'] . $ext . 'id="profile-big-img" alt="' . $r['forename'] . ' ' . $r['surname'] . (($r['course'] == 'graphics') ? ' Graphic Design' : ' Illustration') . '" /></p>' . PHP_EOL;
                }
```

Comment: Any chance you took a peek at the resulting HTML?

Comment: Where does $tempext come from at show time?

Comment: I'd suggest to close this kind of questions immediately for the lack of resulting HTML. And any sane community would accept it for sure. Not this one of course.

Comment: Yes, at the moment I'm getting a warning: "Warning: exif_imagetype() [function.exif-imagetype]: Filename cannot be empty in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gdi/profile.php on line 174" which I'm guessing is referring to `['temp_name']` in the `$exifType` variable? I'm not a PHP developer, so debugging this is a bit of a mission.

Comment: If I take out the variables and switch statement, the jpg's show up fine, and gif's and png's show up as the unavailable.gif

Comment: In second code block you're already returning dot-prefixed extension. Hence no `case` statement matches it.

Comment: Ah I see, but even without the dot-prefix extension in the variable the result is the same. I'm guessing it has to do with how the url is being called into the div?

Answer (score 4):

The most reliable way would be to use [FileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php).

Comment: he don't need no file type detection, I am afraid, but just a little common sense with his code (just like any other question on this god blessed site).

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to trace the issue when code is bit CREAMY ;)

Lets check what is the issue with your images first from command line :

a) open Terminal
b) cd to dirctory with images ( probably web a directory) 
c) Run this on ( copy +past + Enter)

```
 php -r  ' $dh= opendir(".");while(($file=readdir($dh))!==false){ if(!is_dir($file)){ $tp=exif_imagetype($file);echo "$file:  =====> $tp\n"; } } '
```

The output will be sth like this :

```
...
error.JPG:  =====> 2
features.JPG:  =====> 2
kunfu_panda.jpg:  =====> 2
.....
```

compare the codes with Imagetype Constants provided by php .

That will be first Step towards the solution.

Comment: Ok, there are currently 2 imagetypes: `IMG_JPG` and `IMG_GIF`. Nobody has uploaded `IMG_PNG` or `IMG_JPEG` yet, but I'm assuming it'll happen at some point in the future.

Comment: Sorry, the Imagetype Constants are `IMAGETYPE_GIF` and `IMAGETYPE_JPG`, not `IMG_`

Answer (score 0):

you can check with the [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function. I'm pretty sure it should work.